# PHP include() and require() file

Tags: php

I have the following files

*classes/Database.php*

```
require_once("config/config.php");
...
```

*config/config.php*

```
...
```

The problem is:

*include/validateNick.php*

```
require_once("../classes/Database.php");
...
```

In "include/validateNick.php" included "../classes/Database.php" but "Database.php" can't include "config/config.php", it shows a error: No such file or directory.

I know I can change it to `require_once("../config/config.php")`, but I have other php in root folder needs to include "Database.php" (like the following)

*register.php*

```
require_once("classes/Database.php");
...
```

How to solve this problem?

Sorry if my question not clear.

Comment: Use full paths to those files instead of relative ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your Database.php:

```
require_once("config/config.php");
```

You forgot to `../` that path, so the require is effectively looking for:

```
require_once('/path/to/site/classes/config/config.php');
```

instead of the proper

```
require_once('/path/to/site/config/config.php');
```

Try

```
require_once('../config/config.php');
```